# Auto update Wordpress user data when editing their order details in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, user-data

In Woocommerce Order edit pages, editing the customer order does not update the customer user details in Wordpress user data.

Is it possible to automatically save customer details after editing the shipping and billing information in their order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this can be done using **`save_post_shop_order`** hook for all billing and shipping customer fields (including "billing email" and "billing phone" fields):

```
add_action('save_post_shop_order', 'update_wp_user_data', 50, 3 );
function update_wp_user_data( $post_id, $post, $update ) {

    // Checking that is not an autosave
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ){
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_invoices_files', 'auto-save-verif' );
            return $post_id;
        }

    // Check the user’s permissions (for 'shop_manager' and 'administrator' user roles)
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_shop_order', $post_id ) ){
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_invoices_files', 'user-roles-verif' );
            return $post_id;
        }

    // Get the customer ID and check if it's valid
    $customer_id = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_customer_user', true );
    if( empty($customer_id) || $customer_id == 0 )
        return $post_id;

    // Set all field keys in arrays
    $field_keys = array('first_name', 'last_name', 'company', 'address_1', 'address_2', 'city',
        'postcode', 'country', 'state');
    $fields_keys2 = array('email', 'phone');

    foreach( $field_keys as $key ){
        if( isset($_POST['_billing_'.$key]) ){
            update_user_meta( $customer_id￼, 'billing_'.$key, sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_billing_'.$key] ) );
        }
        if( isset($_POST['_shipping_'.$key]) ){
            update_user_meta( $customer_id￼, 'shipping_'.$key, sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_shipping_'.$key] ) );
        }
    }

    foreach( $fields_keys2 as $key ){
        if( isset($_POST['_billing_'.$key]) ){
            update_user_meta( $customer_id￼, 'billing_'.$key, sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_billing_'.$key] ) );
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.